# Abrir arquivo php em ordem crescente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uma pasta update/ com arquivos PHP, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são arquivos de atualização do mysql, quando é atualizado logo em seguida o servidor apaga. Quando o cliente não acessa o Admin o arquivo fica lá, quando lançamos outra atualização então soma o arquivo da versão anteior e a mais recente e assim sucessivamente até que ele acesse o Admin para rodar essa atualização.

**Meu problema:**

Não esta rodando na ordem crescente. Preciso fazer com que seja sempre aberto do menor para o maior, pois essa é a ordem da atualização.

**Código:**

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/update/"; 
$diretorio = dir($path); $i = 0;
while($i <= 3){
    $arquivo = $diretorio -> read(); 
    $file = explode("_v", $arquivo);
    if ($file[0] == 'updateSQL'){
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {$('#myModal').modal('show');})</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: false})</script>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Espere... Não feche até acabar.</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe src="../update/<?php echo $arquivo?>" frameborder="0" height="300px" width="100%" onload="resizeIframe(this);"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php 
    }$i++;
} 
$diretorio -> close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve os nomes dos arquivos num array e utilize a função [natcasesort()](http://php.net/natcasesort) para organizá-los alfabeticamente.

Exemplo didático:

```
$base = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$dir = dir($base);
while (false !== ($e = $dir->read()))
    if (is_file($base.$e)) 
        $f[] = $e;
natcasesort($f);
print_r($f);
```

Apenas precisa ter cuidado com a nomenclatura dos arquivos.

Exemplo, **arquivo11.txt** aparecerá antes de **arquivo2.txt** porque o número 1 vem antes do número 2. A ordenação alfabética faz a leitura como strings, por isso, para evitar esse problema, a nomenclatura deve possuir zeros a esquerda caso contenham números sequenciais.

O **arquivo11.txt** ficaria como **arquivo000011.txt**

O **arquivo2.txt** ficaria como **arquivo000002.txt**

A quantidade de zeros a esquerda, vc define conforme o seu caso.

Comment: Só não entendi como determinar o local da pasta onde tem os arquivos, como no meu exemplo acima.

Comment: No seu script, vc usou uma variável global dependente do Apache. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`. Não recomendo para essa finalidade. No exemplo que postei , usei a constante `__DIR__`, a qual retorna o diretório do script corrente. Apenas teste o exemplo.. Dê um `echo $base; exit;` para ver o resultado. Facilmente vc vai perceber e saber implementar o que precisa.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, consegui entender, mas parece que tem um problema, o ultimo arquivo a ser rodado esta no primeiro valor do array que é o ZERO. Veja ``Array ( [1] => updateSQL_v419.php [2] => updateSQL_v420.php [3] => updateSQL_v421.php [0] => updateSQL_v422.php )``

Comment: deve ter feito algo errado..  Note também que há formas de diferentes de fazer. A ideia central é o uso da função natcasesort() para ordenar o array. Normalmente já vem ordenado em ordem alfabética, mas é bom usar a função para garantir que seja mesmo bem ordenado. Quanto ao erro que descreve, não posso avaliar sem saber o quê e como está fazendo a sua adaptação.

Comment: Fiz como informou ``<?php 
$base = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."/update/";
$dir = dir($base);
while (false !== ($e = $dir->read()))
    if (is_file($base.$e)) 
        $f[] = $e;
natcasesort($f);
print_r($f);
?>``

Comment: ahh entendi.. cara.. a saída deu correto.. o que acontece é que os índices do array são preservados, porém a ordem dos mesmos foi modificada corretamente. Observe vc mesmo a saída do print_r(). Apesar de ter chave ZERO, o valor está na última posição.

Comment: E qual a solução para isso? :)

Comment: como assim? solução? está  correto... rsrs

Comment: está preocupado em como fazer o laço de repetição? é isso? se for caso use o foreach () porque não precisará se preocupar com a ordem das chaves.

Comment: Como faço para exibir um arquivo por vez? Tem que ser executado um por um, estou usando o ``foreach`` para pegar o nome do arquivo, mas ele exibe todos.

Answer (score -2):

Amigo, além de você poder fazer por um arquivo TXT, se você tiver uma numeração base você pode fazer por este método:

Montando um Array

Você montaria um array com o nome dos arquivos manualmente ou com alguma função de leitura de diretório de PHP.
Com o array pronto no código, irá bastar você alimenta-lo com os diferentes arquivos e poderá rodar através de um while(irei fazer um exemplo em Python só para você entender a lógica):

```
i = 0
numeroDeArquivos = Array.len()
while i < numeroDeArquivos:
    open(Array[i], "a")
```

Answer (score -3):

Bom Dia, Amigo eu tenho uma ideia para você fazer oque deseja: Você pode fazer da seguinte forma cada vez que fazer a atualização você anota em um arquivo txt o nome do arquivo ex:
ARQUIVO TXT = updateSQL_v413.php
e na hora que for a proxima atualização você fará:

ler o arquivo txt deleta as 11 primeiras string = updateSQL_v 
divide array por "." = Array[0] = 413, Array[1] = .php.
pega a posição array[1] e soma + 1.  >>> R: 413 + 1 = 414
o resultado tu vai e puxa a atualização repondo as 11 string primeira e juntando os números + .php que ficaria:

updateSQL_v414.php.

Espero tenha entendido e que ajude.

Comment: Podes exemplificar isso através de código?